# Click the same option again in a select with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next code with a `Select`:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdkg1mzo/18/

The problem is that I want to launch the alert every time a `select` `option` is clicked, although the `option` that was `clicked` is the one that is currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $(".normal option").on("click",function(){
        alert("trigger");
    });
});
```

Comment: For some strange reason, your code works very well in Firefox, but in Chrome it does not

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".normal").on("change",function(){
     //alert("trigger");
      var selectedName = $('#selectId').find(":selected").text();
      console.log('selectedName is: ', selectedName)
      alert(selectedName)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="normal" id="selectId">
    <option value="18">John</option>
    <option value="18">Lorry</option>
    <option value="19">Jerry</option>
    <option value="20">Smith</option>
</select>
```

You could add a half second delay to the alert, so it shows the name after the selection has been made:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".normal").on("change",function(){
     //alert("trigger");
      var selectedName = $('#selectId').find(":selected").text();
      console.log('selectedName is: ', selectedName)
      setTimeout(function () {
      //do something once
      alert(selectedName)
      }, 500);
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="normal" id="selectId">
    <option value="18">John</option>
    <option value="18">Lorry</option>
    <option value="19">Jerry</option>
    <option value="20">Smith</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The "change" event will not be fired under the circumstance that the user selected the same option which was previously selected.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<select class="normal" name="mysel" onChange="show(this);">
<option value="18">John</option>
<option value="18">Lorry</option>
<option value="19">Jerry</option>
<option value="20">Smith</option>
</select>
```

pure javascript

```
<script>
function show(m){
var k=m.options[m.selectedIndex].value;
alert(k);
}
</script>
```

Try this it perfectly works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this, but perhaps you can try Chosen: https://plugins.jquery.com/chosen/.
I don't know why do you want to do this, do you want to reload de page, load Ajax results. Maybe it is unnecessary for user experience and you will not improve it at all.